# Working with Python Module/Library (Scipy)

Tags: python, module, scipy, package

I am new-ish to programming and have a question about the way Python packages and modules are organized and are accessed. I was trying to get a function to calculate permutations and found [scipy.special.perm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.perm.html). My first intuition was that *scipy* was the module, *special* was the class, and *perm* was the function. So I tried this (1):

```
import scipy
scipy.special.perm(5, 4)
```

But I got the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'special'
```

This is what worked (2):

```
import scipy.special
scipy.special.perm(5,4)
```

1. Why did (1) fail?
2. I am trying to understand conceptually how scipy is built/organized. Is scipy a package or a module? After all the error message did refer to it as a module so I am leaning towards the latter.
3. What is scipy.special then? Is it a module?
4. What is the recommended way to 'explore' a new module/package like scipy to understand its nature and how it needs to be called so that I now whether to use (1) or (2)?

Comment: The recommended way is to start with the documentation!  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html#scipy-organization

Answer (score 1):

There are many subpackages inside scipy, most of them are slow to load because they are large Fortran extensions. By default if you `import scipy` it does not load any submodule, so it's useless in most cases. You always want to import the subpackage you need, for example:
`import scipy.special` or better yet `from scipy.special import perm`.
[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/) is a list of available submodules in scipy.